# Which method call's after inserting cell into Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm a little confused with inserting cell into a table view.

When I call `tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)` `tableView` not update immediately after it, inside called function. I think it's call some relevant delegate and data source methods, but which ones?

Also, I have seen that some guys call `insertRows` with `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`. Why do we need to do this if the update happens without these two methods?

Comment: I think that `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` are required in order to "lock" the data for editing process. Without these there is a possibity to get a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberOfRows` && `cellForRowAt` are called when you do insertion  , you need begin & end updates to prevent subsequent calls to numberOfRows in case you have a heavy calls to insertion / deletion to avoid exceptions like number of rows / section before the update isn't equal after adding / removing

now it's recommended to use

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates

inside

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates

Comment: Thank you so much! I have already spent a few days on this. 
performBatchUpdates is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Tableview DataSource methods will be called, to begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view, you need to call `beginUpdates()` followed by `endUpdates()`

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)

Comment: That's wrong. `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` is only needed for **a series of** `insert/delete/move` operations which are supposed to be performed simultaneously. Animation is independent of those methods.

Comment: @vadian yeah you are right, its needed for a series if subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection. I mean that for animating them simultaneously. I'll edit my post

Comment: Yes, but they are **not** needed at all for a **single** operation.